# AWS Reserved Instances In OpsWorks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks

Can AWS Reserved Instances be used in OpsWorks?

If so, how?  Any documentation would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because a reserved instance is just a billing mechanism, not a specific machine - when you buy a reserved instance you are just agreeing ahead of time to pay a certain amount for a certain type of machine (whether you use it or not).

If you already have a reserved instance 'under contract' and have not yet spun it up, if you use Opsworks to spin it up, you will be charge your reserved price while that instance is running.

If you have 3 reserved instances, and you spin up 4 in Opsworks, you will be charge 3 instances at the reserved price, and one at the on demand price.

If you buy 5 reserved instances and only spin up 2 in Opsworks, you still are on the hook for all 5 reserved instances.

Comment: Thank you E.J Brennan, now I understand it.

Comment: How to check if my reserved instance is used on my running instance. Also how to see the mapping?